# Is there automated way to detect which .cpp source files I should be compiling (depending on #include *.h)

Tags: c++, c, compilation

I have old big code base, and since I only need a small subset of the functionality in my main Im looking for a way to automatically detect needed .cpps (asuming they are in the same folder and have matching name as .h files).
Unfortunately I still need a lot of code so going through code by hand is out of the question. 
Is there tool that would go from my "main.cpp" and recursively figure out all the .h files needed, so that I can just do simple string replace (.h -> .cpp) and give it to compiler.

Comment: Is there a reason to not just compile it all and let the linker pull in the symbols you're actually using? You'd only have to do this once if you aren't modifying the original code base.

Comment: it takes 2 min to compile, exe is 7 mb...

Comment: The linker will (usually) only put code into the .exe that the program is actually using, so it's irrelevant whether or not you compile extra stuff - if it's only 2 minutes, then there's no point even worrying about it, just compile it all once, don't recompile it again, and let the linker sort it out.

Comment: For example, if you create a program which `#include`s a single header from Boost, that doesn't mean that the entire Boost library gets linked into your final .exe. The typical way to use Boost is to compile the entire thing once, include whatever headers you need, and tell your linker where to find the compiled definitions. The linker only uses what it needs from that.

Comment: It just seems to me from the way you've described your problem that you're trying to use a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Comment: @JBentley it is irritating for me to dev when compile takes 2 min... idk if I can force the caching of all unmodified object files, but I have ccache installed and it is still 2 min... maybe it is the linking that takes so much time..

Comment: Well, I can't advise you on your specific build tools as I only use Visual Studio, but you definitely shouldn't be recompiling the same .cpp files over and over, if they haven't changed.

Comment: yeah ill ask some make ppl around me :) BTW VS + VA FTW

Answer (score 4):

Most compilers can do this for you, for example GCC and Clang offer `-M` and `-MM` to list all dependencies of a source file. There are other options to exclude system headers, etc. Refer to your compiler's documentation for more information or, if you need help, let us know which compiler you are using.

There is one problem with your approach, though: You can figure out the headers included from `main.cpp`, no problem, but if you want to compile the corresponding `.cpp` files for the headers, these implementation files will typically require other headers which were not directly or indirectly included from `main.cpp` and you need the `.cpp` files of *those* headers as well. Rinse and repeat. :)

If manually iterating the process of finding the `.cpp` files is not an option, you may use a Makefile:

```
CPPFILES := $(wildcard *.cpp)
DEPFILES := $(CPPFILES:%.cpp=%.d)

%.d: %.cpp
    g++ -MM $< -o $@

include $(DEPFILES)

%.o: %.cpp
    @echo "$@"

%.h: %.o
    @:
```

Then call

```
make main.o
```

and let make figure out which other files are needed. The above is of course a simplified example, you may have a more complex directory structure and you will probably need to add some compile options for `g++`, but I hope it's a start.

Comment: Though it seems likely "main.cpp" could `#include "featureA.h"` and then "featureA.cpp" has `#include "featureB.h"`....

Comment: @aschepler: Yepp, I also noticed that and edited the answer to point it out to OP.

Comment: im using g++/clang++ , but like you say problem is still that I have bunch of .cpps that might want other .h.

Comment: Rinse and repeat wasn't a joke. Start with `main.cpp`, find more `.cpp` files through the headers. For these files, use the same trick and see which other `.cpp` files are missing. The set of files will grow and finally this will terminate, no new files will show up after some iterations and then you have the final set of source files you need.

Comment: @DanielFrey I know it wasnt a joke, but I have >1.5 k files... idk if it feasible for me to do it. either way if i dont find any other way i might do my own simple program to do it.

Comment: Why not write a small shell script to automate it? But there's another trick, let me edit the answer and check in a few minutes...

Comment: @DanielFrey I use C++ for everything. :)

Comment: btw i dont think simple script will do because I have -I in command line, either way I need to write a real program I feel .

Comment: Use the right tool for the right task. Writing a C++ program for this seems totally wrong to me. Anyway, check my edit.

Comment: hi, looks good, but i wont accept A for now because  maybe just maybe  somebody already wrote this and maybe just maybe somebody will answer.

Answer (score 1):

Compile your code base into a static library (.lib on Windows). You only need to do this once unless you modify the code base - and even then you will only need to recompile the code you change.

In your executable project, include whichever headers you're using, and include the library in your linker settings. The linker will only link the compiled definitions (from the object files inside the static library) which your executable is actually using into the final .exe.